# Use of the word "ecrã"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu

In some texts of European Portuguese it's common to see the word *ecrã* to refer to a computer screen, but it isn't used in Brazilian Portuguese if I'm not wrong.

I'd like to know what the popular meaning for this word is. Is it used only for computers — or also for TVs and smartphones, for example? In European Portuguese is the word *tela* used for the same purpose?

I know that [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tela) and other sources indicate the words (*ecrã* and *tela*) as synonyms, but I'm looking for the popular use.

Comment: Don’t forget [*pantalha*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pantalha), from Spanish *pantalla* (same sound, different spelling).  French has *écran* here, which is where Portuguese got [*ecrã*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ecrã) (again same sound different spelling).  Portuguese [*tela*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tela) can be any kind of textile or cloth, but has plenty of other senses as well. Note also *[teia](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/teia) de aranha* for spiderweb, also from Latin *tela* but this time with lenition of the intervocalic L; compare Spanish *telaraña* for spiderweb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "ecrã" is just used in Português of Portugal and Mozambique. This word doesn't exist in Brazil.

Ecrã is originally from Frances (écran).

The means of the world is screen/canvas.

Most common used for ecrã are:

- Cinema
- Computers
- Canvas
- Television

Comment: I wouldn't say it doesn't exist in Brazil.  I've heard it occasionally.

Comment: This word doesn't exist in a official way.

Comment: It does exist.  Look it up in Aurelio's Second Edition (it's the one I have here).

Comment: `Ecrã de televisão`

Comment: É uma palavra absorvida do pt-PT pelo pt-BR, mas fica restrita a sinônimo dicionarizado para conhecimento sobre seu significado original. Se recebo um eletrônico com manual pt-PT vou saber o significo, mas farei uso dele ou verei alguém fazendo em pt-BR.